# Ugly-looking integral signs in ConTeXt MkIV

Tags: context, math-fonts

A few days ago, I decided to try out ConTeXt (just for fun), but ran into the following problem. Running the 'context' command on

```
\setuppagenumbering[location=]
\starttext
\startformula
  \int_a^b f(x) \, dx
  \qquad
  \iint_D f(x,y) \, dx \, dy
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

produces the following output, with very strange spacing:

[image: Strange integrals]

(With 'texexec' things look normal, though.)

Why is this, and how can it be fixed? I'm a total newbie when it comes to ConTeXt, so apologies in advance if I'm missing something obvious...

System info: Arch Linux with most texlive packages installed, but running a locally installed ConTeXt in my home directory, as described on the [ConTeXt wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone). I tried both beta (current version: 2013.11.16 12:43) and stable (current version: 2013.05.28 00:36), with the same results.

Comment: I can confirm this. As a temporary fix, use `\int\nolimits` and `\iint\nolimits`. I'll try to see if I can figure out why this is not being done automatically.

Comment: @Aditya: Ah, thanks! So then it's not just me hallucinating... I thought a thing like this would have bothered lots of people, but since I didn't find the slightest hint of that on Google, I was wondering if something was wrong with my setup.

Comment: @Aditya Any news about the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what happened in the meantime, but the issue is definitely fixed in ConTeXt MkIV distributed with TeXlive 2016, see below.

[image]